# Securing mobile client to server communication

Tags: android, security, mobile, https, client-server

I am building a mobile app that communicates to a server. I would like the communication to be as secure as possible, but I have no experience in this field.

Upon app first launch, app submits phone number to server, gets a 6-digits code via SMS and then submit those 6-digits to server. Assuming the 6-digits code is valid, server will then return the mobile app an API secret (long unique string) to be saved on the mobile app. I am doing this, so when the user re-installs the app on a another device, the server will revoke access to the old mobile device (i.e: the API secret will no longer be valid).

Where do I go from here? My intention is using the API secret to secure all future communications from mobile app to server (i.e: all communication following signup). I took the idea from different APIs I worked with previously where I had seen that each API user is given an API key/secret. On those API's I noticed that the API secret is used in the following manner, but I have no idea if that's what I need.

```
params = {"method":  api_function_name,
          "order":  'DESC'
          "key":    CLIENT_SPECIFIC_API_KEY,
         }

params = urllib.urlencode(params) 

H = hmac.new(CLIENT_SPECIFIC_API_SECRET, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
H.update(params)
sign = H.hexdigest()
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do from here?

Answer (score 0):

> what I need to do from here

For good security, one of the first things you should do is to figure out whom or what the communication should be secure against.

One thing to do for this particular app is to design a way for the server to determine which device should replace which device in the "re-install" case.

The code in the question looks like a decent way to authenticate the client over a confidential channel between the client and the server. The client sends `(params, sign)` to the server, right?

Comment: Yes, the client sends params, signed by the CLIENT_SPECIFIC_API_SECRET secret, for any communication that comes following the signup process. CLIENT_SPECIFIC_API_SECRET is saved locally to mobile device upon successful signup. Is there any guideline or a common communication schema similar to this one that I can peek at? Tried to google for something like that, but seems like everyone implements his own proprietary solution.

Answer (score 0):

From your first post I can see you are calculating a hash of the CLIENT_SPECIFIC_API_SECRET. I assume this is so that you can store a hashed form rather than the raw CLIENT_SPECIFIC_API_SECRET? This is commonly done on the server side to prevent password's being exposed in the case of a hack. This is particularly important for service providers for which a single hack could lead to the exposure of a huge number of client passwords.

In terms of using the CLIENT_SPECIFIC_API_SECRET for authentication of the client instance there is definitely prior art. A good basic example of this would be the digest authentication mechanism specified in the [HTTP Authentication RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) - look specifically at the section on Digest Authentication. Note that this RFC shows Digest Authentication for HTTP but the basic principles can be applied outside HTTP. For example, Digest Authentication is also used in IMS SIP.

To authenticate a device you could have a Digest Authentication step every time a device opens a connection to the server. Of course the connection should be encrypted (TCP with SSL) as well to prevent man in the middle attacks.